# Тире перед большими буквами PHP регулярные выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как из `masterAtHome` получить `master-at-home` ?

Answer (score 1):

Это типовая задача преобразования *Camel Case* строк в аналог *Snake Case* (с минусами вместо подчеркиваний).

Вот один из самых простых вариантов преобразования:

```
echo strtolower(preg_replace("/(?!^)([A-Z])/", '-$1', 'masterAtHome'));
```

В примере выше, группа символов `(?!^)` используется для игнорирования заглавной буквы, если она идет первой в строке.

Рабочий пример на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/oF57RQ).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
  echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<!^)([A-Z])/',
    function($match) { return '-'.strtolower($match[1]); },
    'masterAtHome');
```